# .NET 5.0 Web Deploy Package advanced configurations are ignored

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, publish, .net-5, webdeploy

I would like to publish a Blazor Server App targeting .NET 5.0 from command line, using a Visual Studio publish profile that I created choosing "Web Deploy Package" from Publish wizard.

First step, I modified the resulting .pubxml file by setting PackageAsSingleFile=false to avoid creating a single .zip file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <WebPublishMethod>Package</WebPublishMethod>
        <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
        <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
        <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
        <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
        <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
        <ProjectGuid>5b8f7f32-13f8-4523-ac2d-a8004ba24ecb</ProjectGuid>
        <DesktopBuildPackageLocation>C:\publish\installer\</DesktopBuildPackageLocation>
        <PackageAsSingleFile>false</PackageAsSingleFile>
        <DeployIisAppPath>Default Web Site/MyService</DeployIisAppPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
```

I then launched Publish with Visual Studio, but the publish completed with this message in Output:

```
Package "Basket.Service.zip" is successfully created *as single file* at the following location
```

First step, failed: i would like to generate an archive folder instead of a single .zip file. The property PackageAsSingleFile is getting ignored by Visual Studio.

As I've always done with older ASP.NET 4.5 projects, I then customized the .pubxml file to:

- fix the path in the generated package, as suggested in [this](http://sedodream.com/2015/02/20/VisualStudioWebPackagesFixingThePathInTheGeneratedWebPackage.aspx) article from Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi ([profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105999/sayed-ibrahim-hashimi)).
- create a custom Logs folder and avoid deleting its content if already exists (MsDeploySkipRules attached to AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest).

I tried calling the publish profile from a custom MSBuild script:

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(SourceDir)\MyService\MyService.csproj"
  Properties="Configuration=$(BuildConfiguration);DeployOnBuild=true;VisualStudioVersion=16.0;
  PublishProfile=Publish to package;
  DesktopBuildPackageLocation=$(InstallerDir);PackageAsSingleFile=false;
  DeployIisAppPath=Default Web Site/MyService"
  ContinueOnError="false" />
```

or from a single "dotnet publish" command:

```
dotnet publish "C:\Source\Middleware\basket\source\Basket.Service\Basket.Service.csproj"  -p:PublishProfile="Publish to package"
```

The result is, unfortunately, the same and all the advanced configurations are simply ignored. It seems that every suggestion that I can find about analog problems doesn't do the trick, when applied to .NET Core.

Comment: `The result is, unfortunately, the same and all the advanced configurations are simply ignored.` You mean you use  .pubxml or MSBuild,all the advanced configurations will be ignored.

Comment: Yes. It seems that publish (performed with any tool) goes on with defaults, ignoring every custom setting. Also, if I add a file to .csproj with CopyToOutputDirectory=PreserveNewest directive, the file is always overwritten, regardless of the changes made (or not made) to the file.